# Using Postal with QueueBackgroundWorkItem - The request lifetime scope cannot be created > because the HttpContext is not available

Tags: c#, autofac, postal

I'm using Postal to send emails.
My application is an ASP.net MVC application. I use Autofac (MVC5 integration)

I've set up Postal like so:

```
        dynamic email = new Email("TemplateName");
        email.To = "test@email.com";
        email.From = "sendertest@email.com";

        email.TemplateValue = "This is a value";

        var service = new EmailService();

        HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
        {
            service.Send(email);
        });
```

This fails with the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   Autofac.Integration.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The request lifetime scope cannot be created
>   because the HttpContext is not available.

```
   at Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RequestLifetimeScopeProvider.GetLifetimeScope(Action`1 configurationAction)  
   at Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.get_RequestLifetimeScope()  
   at Autofac.Integration.Mvc.AutofacDependencyResolver.GetService(Type serviceType)  
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.DefaultViewPageActivator.Create(ControllerContext controllerContext, Type type)  
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)  
   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.RenderView(IView view, ViewDataDictionary viewData, ControllerContext controllerContext, ImageEmbedder imageEmbedder)  
   at Postal.EmailViewRenderer.Render(Email email, String viewName)  
   at Postal.EmailService.CreateMailMessage(Email email)  
   at Postal.EmailService.Send(Email email)  
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , EmailService , Object )  
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecuteVoid2[T0,T1](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)  
   at EmailSender.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Handle>b__0(CancellationToken ct) in .....EmailSender.cs:line 42  
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.<>c__DisplayClass91_0.<QueueBackgroundWorkItem>b__0(CancellationToken ct)  
   at System.Web.Hosting.BackgroundWorkScheduler.<RunWorkItemImpl>d__7.MoveNext()
```

If I take the `service.Send(email);` out of the `QueueBackgroundWorkItem` it works.

I understand this is because `HttpContext.Current` isn't available - but is there a way I can send emails using Postal on a background thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postal is able to just create a `MailMessage` object, without sending it. See http://aboutcode.net/postal/create-mail-message.html

So you could do this within the MVC controller action, while the HttpContext is still alive.

Then, send the `MailMessage` in your background thread, using your own instance of `SmtpClient`.

Comment: Hi  I am facing this same problem can you give me more guidance on how to implement this solution. How to send the email after it has been created using own instance of smtpClient

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a custom view engine?

As suggested [here](http://aboutcode.net/postal/outside-aspnet.html), is possibile to use postal outside of ASP.NET request scope (I know you're using MVC 5, but looks like the same situation to me).

If you still getting error, probably is a problem of Autofac registration: did you register something in the request scope, like this `.InstancePerRequest();` ? In that case Autofac will no be able to resolve that components outside of the pipeline.